# What is the best way to check whether my cased articles are correct

Tags: article

I am self learning German.

Currently I am going through one online worksheet of cases.They don't have answers mentioned in it. I want to make sure that my answers are correct.

What's the best way to check online whether my articles are in correct case?

Comment: It's a bit moot to try and learn from questions with no answers. That is BTW true for anything you try to learn. I'd recommend you try another method.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with the german language, but with learning methods.

Answer (score 2):

Pick a German text. Ctrl+C-Ctrl+V it on a text editor. Perform a search for

> der, die, das, dem, den, dessen, deren,...

Replace each one of them by, say, `____`.

Fill the blanks, and compare your answers with the original.

Comment: you are not answering the question. he didn't ask how to study articles more effectively in general but rather how he can check his answers for that particular worksheet. i like your idea though

Comment: @LonelyNeuron I doubt the actual question has an answer for a particular worksheet (which explains why the question is now closed)

Comment: the second answer to this question directly addresses the problem

Comment: @LonelyNeuron Where is there the particular worksheet you were talking about?

Answer (score 2):

Find a German* person in social media and ask him/her. I suppose most people will be nice enough to help you.

Or if you happen to live at a place where you have a chance to meet a living German*, go visit him or her. Could be in a pub, by the way.

*<sub>Read this as "German-speaking with good command of that language". Passport brand is obviously not the issue here, and there are other people out there who speak perfect German without qualifying as "Germans".</sub>